# Updating UI on the main thread while using socket.IO ios library in the background

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, sockets, ios7

I am facing a problem trying to understand how to update the UI on the main thread based on a receive event of a `socket running` on the `background thread`.

The socket.IO library (https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) implements the `receiveEvents` as delegates for the `socketIO` object. How do I notify my main thread when I receive an event on the background thread?

I found a solution on stack that says:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0), ^{
//load your data here.
// Call socket.IO library? How do I check for a receive event?
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //update UI in main thread.
        });
});
```

I am using two classes, one for my `socket.IO` connection and the other a `ViewController` that contains my UI. I would like to know if there is a correct approach to updating the UI based on the receiveEvent delegate happening in the background.

Comment: This is the correct approach, always update UI on the main thread

Comment: Do you know how I might notify my main thread of a receive event in the background thread?

Comment: you can use notification or add observer to call the method to update your UI

Comment: Okay, thank you! I will look into observer pattern, that seems like the approach that I need.